# VBA Excel 2007 help to speed up code to hide rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code that automatically hides rows if a value in the row is equal to "". My range of values is A37:A400. Because my range is so big my previous VbA is to slow and looks one line at a time. Any ideas to make a fast code that will go though this large list and hide rows in a quick fashion. Right now it takes about a minute to hide the rows which is too Long.

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A37:A400")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A37:A400")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Yes, I want to hide any blank value. But the above code takes way to long. If possible i need something as fast as a filter

Comment: I have and IF statement in the Cells and if the statement is not true then it equals "".

Comment: I don't see how this can work if your code shows  `If Not IsEmpty(cell)` then how does `if Cell.Value` ever get executed?

Comment: John, please post the comment under my post, so it's all together (and delete the old posts under your question)

Comment: After discussion, this can't be resolved as there are too many variables which are bespoke and too unique to OP

Comment: Any reason you're hiding rows this way rather than just applying a filter?

Comment: Want it to happen automatically

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` just before your hiding code, and add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after your hiding code. Normally this trick speeds up most VBA macros by about 10x because the application does not have to keep redrawing itself as the code runs.

This should help in your case because you are checking each cell individually and hiding the row individually versus doing a batch hide of rows.

Comment: I just noticed Raystafarian's comment in Dave Rook's answer so I apologize for repeating exactly what he wrote. However, I still feel the `ScreenUpdating = False` trick usually helps in general to speed up most macros

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your code even works.

You have the following 2 lines

```
If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        If cell.Value = "" Then
```

If the first line is not empty, then 2nd line will always return false. The first line is saying "if the cell is not empty" and the next line says "if the line is empty"... Well, it's already been evaluated to not be empty. Therefore, you should never be able to hide the row so I'm lost as to how your code works - I suspect there is something else going on outside the code but...

However, this works fine on my machine

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A1600")
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If            
    Next
End Sub
```

I have 1600 rows, it takes 5 seconds or so to execute

Comment: i TRIED YOU CODE, Still takes about a minute to run through everything. Any ideas for something faster

Comment: Could it be because i have so many other formulas based off the value?

Comment: John, I *think* so. I think we need to test a few things really to find out why. We need to know if the fault is with Excel, the worksheet or computer! First off, can you please open a new worksheet, and in row A1 - A400 please populate some of the fields, and leave others blank. Then run your code. This will indicate if the fault is with the worksheet you were working on.

Comment: I tried it in a blank spreadsheet, took about 5 seconds. But my sheet still takes a minute

Comment: Then the fault is due to other formulae on the page. And there is no way I can guess what that is or could be, I'm sorry. You need to consider a different approach if timing is an issue.

Comment: Try to set `application.screenupdating` to false and also see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418575/excel-vba-skip-calculating-formula-in-macro)

Comment: @DaveRook Regarding `IsEmpty` vs. `= ""`: two different things. IsEmpty checks to see if a value has been initialized, where as `= ""` is checking to see if an initialized String contains any characters. `= ""` should fail (and possibly throw an exception) if the variable was set to "Null", whereas `IsEmpty` would be False (it's NOT empty, because it contains Null).

Comment: Thanks @techie007 ... This is different to .Net and I just assumed it was the same. However, the case above, if the cell is not initialised, then there can't be any value so it does look like the code isn't needed (or did I still miss the point)...?